# how to extract these specific links usuing mechanize in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, mechanize-ruby

I've been trying but I cant get these specific links on this page:
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/top-free-apps
I want to get each one of the links on the left side of this page, *entertainment* for example, but I cant find the right reference to get them.
it's the script:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/top-free-apps")
page.links_with(???)
```

what should I put instead of ??? so that I cant get those links?
I've tried stuff like:

```
page.links_with(:class => 'categoryNav navText')
```

OR

```
page.links_with(:class => 'categoryNav')
```

OR

```
page.links_with(:class => 'navText')
```

etc
can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Using page.parser, you can access the underlying Nokogiri object. This allows you to use [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) to make your search.

The idea here is that all those links to have a 'data-ov' attribute that starts with 'AppLeftMerch'. This is something we can use to identify them using the  '[starts-with](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp)' function.

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/top-free-apps")

page.parser.xpath("//a[starts-with(@data-ov,'AppLeftMerch')]").each do |link|
  puts link[:href]
end
```